# Get current Date Object of a timezone

Tags: javascript, react-native, timezone

what is the best way of getting current time in selected timezone as Date Object. I am using Following code to get current time at selected timezone in react native.

Eg. 
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Indian/Christmas' })

The output of this code is a string but I need it in Date Object. Every time I convert back to New Date() , it takes default timezone but I need custom timeZone. I also tried using moment library and momentTimeZone bu could not get correct output. Anyone can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

`Date` also takes a `dateString` as an argument and most of the string formats should work (that `Date.parse()` [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Using_Date.parse())) :

```js
> now = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Indian/Christmas' })
'12/26/2018, 3:51:28 PM'
> now_obj = new Date(now)
2018-12-26T14:51:28.000Z
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is I need to convert the string object obtained from new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Indian/Christmas' }) back to Date Object without changing timeZone of date Object.  DatepickerIOS in React native component only takes Date Object as input. So, I need to convert the string to Date object. Every time I convert it back to Date , it takes default timezone , I need to keep timeZone unchanged.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. I see now that I misinterpreted your use case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can not do that unless you change your OS timezone to you want. You can define function instead of Date object as below:

```js
function getCustomDate(zone) {
    return new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: zone })
}
```